# How Can I solve convert Json to Dart Data Model problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to passing data from KML files to Dart with json but `I am getting

```
I/flutter (13849): type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'
```

I am trying different options but cant solved. How can I solve this problem ?

The data I'm trying to access :

```
print(value.folder.placemark[a].multiGeometry.polygonkml
                .innerBoundaryIs.linearRing[c].coordinates);
```

Used data models :

```
class InnerBoundaryIs {
  List<LinearRing> linearRing;

  InnerBoundaryIs({this.linearRing});

  InnerBoundaryIs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['LinearRing'] != null) {
      linearRing = new List<LinearRing>();
      json['LinearRing'].forEach((v) {
        linearRing.add(new LinearRing.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.linearRing != null) {
      data['LinearRing'] = this.linearRing.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class LinearRing {
  String tessellate;
  String coordinates;

  LinearRing({this.tessellate, this.coordinates});

  LinearRing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    tessellate = json['tessellate'];
    coordinates = json['coordinates'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['tessellate'] = this.tessellate;
    data['coordinates'] = this.coordinates;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Json file is big therefore I added this used part as image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ODcy.png)

Comment: Can you please add your json resonse here so i can check it

Comment: Are you converted data from file?

Comment: I added json response partialy becase response have big data and ı am converting data from a KML file with PHP then made json for dart

Comment: use this tool to generate model and direct access using objects https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Or if you're in VSC, there's a great extension for Dart Data Classes (always a good thing to have anyway) that happens to be able to parse JSON to generate dart classes for it, all within the editor...

Answer (score 0):

You will get this type of error when there is no string exist with same name on json response. For example a simple JSON response is { 'status': 1, 'msg': " List is here"} but if server is down or for any other reason, the response from the response do not have the exact string name 'status' and 'msg' then the dart will throw an Error dynamic => null. Because dart is unable to detect the string name as 'status'.

I will suggest you to always use [Free Online Json to Dart](https://www.dripcoding.com/json-to-dart/) convertor to make dart file. So please one check the JSON response and dart class. Make sure both having same string names.